# Can I place boxes three in each row, equally spaced and glued to container on left and right?

Tags: html, css

I think this can't be done in CSS, but there are people here who know more than I do. ;-)

I have a couple of boxes inside a container. I want the boxes to be three in each row and in contact with the container at left and right. And I want equal horizontal spaces between them.

Can that be done? There is a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/XtCQJ/1/

And what about the last (second) row? What can be done to the spacing there?

```
<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>    

#container {
    background: green;
    width: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#container div {
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 27%;
    height: 30%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: I have an idea of what you're looking for, but can you draw a simple picture demonstrating exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: Sounds interesting, @RayanBouajram. Problem with fiddle. Please read the second paragraph above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by logical use of widths and margins. [Check this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/XtCQJ/4/) as an example. The relevant code is below:

```
#container div {
    width: 32%; 
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
#container div:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The total width for each "line" adds up to 100%: three 32% widths, and two 2% margins. The third item on every line has it's right margin removed with an nth selector.

You don't have to use percentages, but the concept will always remain the same - divide up your widths and margins so as to fit their parent perfectly (or just slightly less), and be wary of extra pixels from borders.

Note: I would advise against using percentage heights, as they can cause problems.

Comment: That nth-child(3) looks interesting. I knew I was not the one who knows this best. ;-)

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the way to do it. Thanks John! (I will have to complicate my style sheet a bit since I switch between 1, 2 or 3 boxes beside each other depending on screen width, but anyway it will work. When I just happen to place the CSS code at the right place. ;-) )

Comment: Note: In this case the container width is not fixed so I can't use fix widths on the boxes either. Unless I use CSS calc, but that is yet discouraged, or?

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with CSS calc, but I'm certain you could, and this would seem like a perfect time to use it.