# Do I need font-size:0?

Tags: css, fonts

In a previous question I got some excellent answers for placing 3 boxes in a row:

[Can I place boxes three in each row, equally spaced and glued to container on left and right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738711/can-i-place-boxes-three-in-each-row-equally-spaced-and-glued-to-container-on-le/)

There is a nagging problem there. For the solution to work I have to put `font-size:0` on the container. Which means I have to specify absolute values for fonts in the boxes.

Not really what I always want. Can I avoid that font-size:0?

Here is a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/BUYZ3/2/

Comment: for information , because of IE you should set `font-size` to `0.01px` , else it doesn't take `font-size:0;`, ... when you really need it of course.

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus. Is that needed with latest IE too?

Comment: Eh, I forgot how to start it... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can avoid it by not leaving any whitespace in the markup between those elements..

One way to do that is to use html comments between the elements (*in order to keep the code formatting you want*)

```
<div id="container"><!--
    --><div>one</div><!--
    --><div></div><!--
    --><div>three</div><!--
    --><div>four</div><!--
    --><div>five</div><!--
--></div>
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/BUYZ3/4/

The other is to just remove the whitespace

```
<div id="container"><div>one</div><div></div><div>three</div><div>four</div><div>five</div></div>
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/BUYZ3/5/

---

For this specific example you could also (*more appropriate really..*) float the elements..

```
float:left;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BUYZ3/6/

Comment: I see, thanks Gaby. Is that the only way? Is there no CSS code that can handle it?

Comment: @Leo, you could float the elements instead for this example.. not sure what you try to accomplish though... (*added demo in answer*)

Comment: Oh, that was great to know! So you mean that using `float:left` instead of `display:inline-box` avoids the font size problem? I have never seen that before. Or, hm. I have. But it did not came up in my head when I needed it. ;-)

Comment: That float actually solved my previous problem too! With a completely new code. I needed the first block to be as wide as 2 or three blocks + spacing. Using calc (which seems supported but is very annoying with spaces (who coded the parser ;-) ) it is easy to get what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/EJ9qe/1/